app available for installation in internaltest & closed test but not visible in the device and cannot be found in the device after sucesseful install
I'm developpig a React-Native app and it has been released to internal testing and closed tesging.
I can go onto the Play Store and download the app
Problem is, after successful installation I cannot see the app in my menu and in the whole phone exept in parameters/settings, I can only see the 'uninstall' button and no button to 'open' the app both in the playstore and in the device settings
Is there something I am missing? i am struggling and i have already spent two or three days on this without any success or solution

So you are not able to find your app after install? Have you tried searching with the app name? It's not possible that the app is installed and cannot be find in your device. Can you try uninstalling it for all users and then installing it again?
